# Mixing private and public repository in Git workflow

Tags: git

I'm fairly new to Git and I'm trying to setup a workspace and workflow. Could someone give me some advice please. I believe that with Git everything is possible but I want to follow the rules here.

So I use Github to host one public and one private repository. The public repository is my project's official code and the private one is used only by me so I can work on different computers.

I want to work as much as possible on my private repository. Here I have branches where I investigate some ideas.

When I want to release something I want to pick some commits from my private repository and merge them to public. I also want that my public changes appear as one single commit without any history.

I've been reading and I think rebase is the way to go when sending stuff into public so I can pick and squash what I want.

What do you guys think? Is this doable? or it has any major issues? I guess I could try it but I don't want to get stuck in something that isn't right to begin with.

Comment: A good overview of git, workflows and the differences between `git pull` and `git rebase` can be found [in the progit.org book](http://progit.org/book/). Your workflow would pull from your `private` repo, and commit changes. Then `git push` back to `private`. When you're happy with your repo, you can `git push` from `private` to `public`, to fast-forward your `public` to the same state as your `private`. The progit book has info about cherry-picking commits, and squashing commits if you're worried about the history shown on `public`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everyone should read Pro Git by Scott Chacon before tackling any sort of project with Git. Without wanting to plug his book beyond a strong recommendation, he pretty much sums up this workflow on p124.

Totally doable.

Treat your private as your dev fork and your public as your production fork. Be really strict with merges between the two.

Comment: Thanks. It's good to know that this is a good approach. Regarding merging between the two branches. My local repositories both have 2 branches: private-master -> github-private-repo/master; public-master -> github-public/master. How should I do with the rebase? If I try to do it between the two masters I don't get any commits to pick, so I'm guessing it must be done some other way.

Comment: Holy cow! I finally understood how this works. At least to get it working. So sweet. :)

Comment: Best of luck! Git is awsum :) It's the reason I switched from Windows to Linux.

Comment: Note that in the new version of the book it is on page 127. It's called "Integration-Manager Workflow"